# use 2 private keys to encrypt content that could not be accessed by single key owner

Tags: encryption, private-key, pgp, symmetric

I need to provide a security mechanism like one used in the "2-key nuke button" of nuclear submarines movies :D.

I need to encrypt files that no-one could decrypt, neighter the one owning one of the encryption keys.

Content could be decrypted only with the acnowlodge of both the signers.

Is that possible with pgp or other known algorithms?

Thanks.

Comment: The simplest solution is to randomly generate a 32 byte long encryption key for AES-256, encrypt your material with that key, split the key into 2 16 bytes long subkeys and encrypt each subkey with RSA, EC or some else asymmetric encryption scheme (use the public key). For decryption you need to decrypt the (encrypted) subkey with 2 private keys, merge the subkeys and decrypt the material.

Comment: You mentioned PGP/GPG, so have you tried simply doubly encrypting by running GPG(key2, GPG(key1, plaintext))? It is inelegant compared to the method outlined by @MichaelFehr and twice as slow, but it has the advantage that the software (gpg) already exists and you seem to be familiar with it.